# Laravel - HTTP Facades Request to store image in form

Tags: php, html, laravel, request, http-post

The form data included text and image to store in database. How can I use Facades like `Categories::create(Request::input());` or `$path = $request->photo->store('cat_img');`to store all data included image path?

Here is the form HTML:

```
<form id="w0" action="{{URL::to('categories/create')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <label class="control-label" for="categories-cat_name">Category Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="categories-cat_name" class="form-control"
               name="cat_name" maxlength="250">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group field-categories-cat_img required">
        <label class="control-label" for="categories-cat_img">Category Image</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="cat_img" value=""><input type="file" id="categories-cat_img" name="cat_img">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want just upload image and store it's detail to database or something else ?